# why does printing variable[array] output array elements?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, while-loop

During a Quiz,we were supposed to find the output of the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
     int a[3] = {10,12,14};
     int i = 0;
     while(i<3)
     {
         printf("%d\n ",i[a]);
         i++;
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

The Output of this Code is:

```
10 12 14
```

I have read through various books and websites but still i do not get how this code is working.
I assumed the code will have a compilation error since i is not an array but somehow in this case it prints the above mentioned output.
I experimented by passing pointers instead of the array and it still worked.
It would be very kind of you to explain since my lecturer won't reply.

Comment: `a[b]` is defined as `*(a+b)`.  As such, it's a commutative operator, since `*(a+b)` equals `*(b+a)` equals `b[a]`.

Comment: @Hamza Kamal Instead of these two statements printf("%d\n ",i[a]);
         i++; you could write printf("%d\n ",i++[a]);